# How to use bootstrap css in Grails rendering plugin template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, rendering, grails-plugin

I am using rendering plugin for generating reports. But, when using bootstrap css in template file it throws an error:

```
org.xhtmlrenderer.render.AnonymousBlockBox cannot be cast to 
org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableCellBox
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to eliminate the "float: left;" in your css class definition like mentioned in this answer: https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=144